# What does this error means? java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request code 324 cannot be within the range reserved by the Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I'm using Parse and Facebook SDK on an Android App.

All I want is to share a link on the user timeline and check if the user accepted it.

But seems that for that I need to ask the user to log in, then ask for "publish_actions" and then show the sharing window, because only if logged in and with publish permission the callback from the ShareDialog will bring the postID (which I think is the only way to check if the user posted to his timeline) (PLEASE let me know if there is another way!). And for that, I'm concatenating those steps inside the other's callbacks.

The first problem is that I don't know how to handle the "**requestCode**"s.

On my **onActivityResult** Parse says that I should call **ParseFacebookUtils**.onActivityResult() like this:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ParseFacebookUtils.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

while Facebook documentation tells me to call **callbackManager**.onActivityResult() like this:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

I realized that **the first one** only calls callbacks from **ParseFacebookUtils** functions while **the second one** only calls callbacks from **Facebook SDK**. But Parse doesn't do everything, and I need to work with both, so how should I do it?

I tried initializing the ParseFacebookUtils with my own "**requestCode**" like this:

```
ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(this, 324);
```

(324 is the number on the error on the title here)

and then I changed my **onActivityResult** to something like this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 324:
            ParseFacebookUtils.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            break;
        case 320:
            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

320 being the **requestCode** explicitly declared on the **ShareDialog** like this:

```
 shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
          ...
       }, PARSE_FACEBOOK_REQUESTCODE);
```

But very weird things happens:

1 - Sometimes I get **requestCode**s different than those two, like 325. Which means my switch-case way of dealing with it will not work. So I accept suggestions for how to deal with that.

2 - Sometimes I get the error on the title: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request code **324** cannot be within the range reserved by the Facebook SDK. Which I really don't understand since it comes from ParseFacebookUtils calls that should manage that by it's own.

And the weirdest thing is that not even "Google" knows this error. It returns 0 results even for "cannot be within the range reserved by the Facebook SDK."

Well if you read until here I thank you very much. And if you can explain to me how to fix it I would really appreciate.

Comment: Wanted a little more information before submitting an answer. Are you simply trying to login with ParseFacebookUtils and then use the ShareDialog?

Comment: Yes. But I need publish permissions to get the post-id.